# Excluding Internal IP's using Advanced/Custom segments

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

So for my organisation, I need to retroactively report on traffic to areas of my site that were not previously filtered by IP (we have a new filtered profile set up now).

My question is, how can I filter out these IP addresses using a custom/advanced segment and NOT a filtered profile? Is this possible in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that you unable to retroactively filter by IP; this is to keep the data anonymous and in line with Google Analytics privacy policy.

The nearest that you can do is filter by ISP by choosing [hostname] I know this may be of no use though, however, if you combine the hostname with the city that you are based, you will have a more rigid solution, although it certainly isn't a bulletproof solution, it may help.